# protractor browser.takeScreenshot promises aren't waiting for image to be written?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to do some post production stitching of browser screenshots but `browser.takeScreenshot()` promises resolve before the image hits the filesystem fully.

This is causing corruption downstream in my image processing.

```
return browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream(fullPathAndFilename);
    stream.write(new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
    stream.end();
});
```

even if I add a `browser.sleep()` it seems the image isn't "ready" for me until much much later.

This leads me to think, that I'll need to separate the post-production routine ?

Comment: There is a module specially about that. Can't remember the exact name, but protractor search in NPM should expose it.

Comment: Try returning a promise for the `stream`s `end` event (or whatever it is called) from your `then` callback.

Comment: @Bergi please post that solution and I'll give you points, that was it.